# Composer install fails to clone

Tags: php, git, composer-php, drupal-8

I am trying to do a `composer install` on a new Drupal project, and it fails with the following error:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage.git via https, ssh, git protocols, aborti
  ng.

  - https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage.git
    Cloning into 'web/libraries/backbone.localstorage'...
    done.
    sh: line 0: cd: web/libraries/backbone.localstorage: No such file or directory

  - git@github.com:jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage.git
    Cloning into 'web/libraries/backbone.localstorage'...
    done.
    sh: line 0: cd: web/libraries/backbone.localstorage: No such file or directory

  - git://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage.git
    Cloning into 'web/libraries/backbone.localstorage'...
    done.
    sh: line 0: cd: web/libraries/backbone.localstorage: No such file or directory
```

System details:

```
macOS 10.12.6
git version 2.18.0
Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59
PHP 7.0.30 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 00:52:06) ( NTS )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.30, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

It's puzzling because my co-workers do not get this error, and they have similar machines, running the same OS, and composer/php/git version.

I have tried the following to no avail:

- Re-installing git with `brew reinstall git`
- Remove the vendor directory with `rm -rf vendor`
- Clear composer cache with `composer clear-cache`
- Remove the localStorage package from `composer.json` (the exact same error appears, even if cache is cleared)
- Running composer install with the `--prefer-dist` flag
- Running composer install with the `--prefer-source` flag

I've also tried running `composer update`, and I get this error:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout '/Users/delucac/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.drupal.org-project-ma
  illog/' 'web/modules/contrib/maillog' --dissociate --reference '/Users/delucac/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.
  drupal.org-project-maillog/' && cd 'web/modules/contrib/maillog' && git remote set-url origin 'https://git.drup
  al.org/project/maillog' && git remote add composer 'https://git.drupal.org/project/maillog'

  Cloning into 'web/modules/contrib/maillog'...
  done.
  sh: line 0: cd: web/modules/contrib/maillog: No such file or directory
```

I've Googled around and found several threads with the same/similar issue, but no resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

I'm not sure why, and the error doesn't really indicate this, but removing this line from my `.bashrc` fixes the issue:

```
export CDPATH='~:~/Sites'
```

This provides "auto-bookmarks" to `cd` completion for any top-level directory in either Home or Sites, and obviously modifies some path, but I'm still confuses why this caused a problem.

If anyone has any further insight into this I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you have `web` directory in `~` or `~/Sites`?

Comment: I had it in `~/Sites`, but just to test, I tried moving the project directory to `/tmp` and re-running the `composer install` with the `CDPATH` options in tact, and it still failed.

Comment: It probably fails because with your `CDPATH` settings `cd` will first search for `web` directory in `~`, then in `~/Sites`, and then in your current directory. In your case it will find `~/Sites/web` and go in that way, so it never try to search in your current directory. You may try `CDPATH='.:~:~/Sites'` to make it more predictable.